# Simple OAuth Role assignment within a Scope

Tags: 8, tokens, authentication-authorization

I have a web app that has multiple scopes under a single OAuth consumer. I want the user's Drupal role to be used when logging in.

In simple OAuth, I have created 1 consumer that has 2 scopes: `editor_user` and `regular_user`.

I run oauth/token with `grant_type=password`, this returns a token that covers the `authenticated`, `editor_user` and `regular_user` roles.

When logging in as a user with role `regular_user` and forcefully setting the scope to `editor_user`, the user role gets set to `editor_user` !

This seems highly unsafe. User roles need to be properly enforced on the backend.

I would expect the Drupal backend to correctly check for a user's roles, and ignore any scopes that do not match. Regardless of whether the consumer itself is allowed access to more scopes than a user.

Is there a way of restricting the token to the user's role within a scope that can contain multiple?

So, if a `regular_user` authenticates, but a front-end user manipulates the request, still only the role of `regular_user` is assigned to him? Not the roles that are defined in the scope?

**Additional information**

If I request a list of articles, as a regular user with scope properly set to `regular_user`, I see the articles (except for a field for which regular users don't have view permissions, thanks to field_permissions module).

When setting the scope for a regular user to `editor_user`, I don't receive any articles. Not sure if this is thanks to a security mechanism or due to a bug.

My reasoning would be that the `editor_user` scope does not match the user's assigned roles and hence gets removed. Which leaves an empty scope and ... ? gives the same permissions as for anonymous users? Not sure about this. 
Anonymous users should see the article list too, though.